# Is there a code in Angular to display the selected image to be displayed as the large image

Tags: angular

I have an image already displayed small, if I click on that image, I want that image to be displayed as the bigger image. 
 `<div class="main-image" [innerHTML]="item.largeImages[0] | displayImage:'product-image'"></div>`

The smaller image is displayed as 
`<div *ngIf="!first" class="small-image
   [innerHTML]="image | displayImage:'product-image'" (click)="displaySelectedImage()"></div>`

```
 ` public displaySelectedImage(index: number) {
        const img = this._item.smallImages[index];
        console.log(img);
         this.item.largeImages.push(img);
         this._item.smallImages[index] === this.item.largeImages[0];
    }`
```

This code didnt work, I am not sure if I am writing the code correct. Could someone help.
Please let me know if you need additional information. I am just new to this technology and new to stack also. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe to you are trying to show a preview of a image, that is already being displayed.

You can try below approach:

update your component:

```
@ViewChild('imgDiv') imgDiv: ElementRef;
imageSrc = '';
```

inject Renderer in your component

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer2){
}
```

update your display method and add one new method:

```
public displaySelectedImage(src) {
  this.imageSrc = src;
  this.renderer.setStyle(this.imgDiv.nativeElement,'display','block');
}

hideImage(){
   this.renderer.setStyle(this.imgDiv.nativeElement,'display','none')
}
```

update your template

```
<div #imgDiv class="img-div">
  <span (click)="hideImage()">&times;</span>
  <img [src]="imageSrc">
</div>
```

update your css

```
.img-div {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 2000;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
 }
```

Pass the image src while calling the display function, you might need to update css as per your need

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the above code. I have no errors, but the image size is smaller and not enlarged when i click on it.